# alert russian text in javascript in asp.net website

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to alert Russian text in JavaScript. I have:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

But what I get is for example: `&#1042;&#1072;&#1096; &#1051;&#1086;&#1075;&#1080;&#1085;`

What can I do about it?

Here is the code in html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20">

<head id="ctl00_htmlHead"><meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

...

in the view source html there is

```
alert("&#1042;&#1072;&#1096; &#1051;&#1086;&#1075;&#1080;&#1085;");
```

but in my ascx file there is:

```
alert("Пароль");
```

Comment: What do you see here? http://jsbin.com/umanam

Comment: It looks like the text is being HTML encoded and the JavaScript is displaying the encoding rather than decoding it.

Comment: i think un javascript you have used `escape()` before displaying it in alert

Comment: i think un javascript you have used `escape()` before displaying it in alert

Comment: I didnt use escape, @Sergio I can see correct alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:
http://www.strictly-software.com/scripts/downloads/encoder.js

and:

```
alert(Encoder.htmlDecode("&#1042;&#1072;&#1096; &#1051;&#1086;&#1075;&#1080;&#1085;"));
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/gMUKY/

This is encoded in html entities not in javascript utf8 format.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the configuration for Auto-Detect UTF-8 encoding without signature.
it should be in Tools -> options -> Text editor

Or make visual studio save the documents in unicode:
Tools -> options -> Environment -> Documents